# Difference between $center and $centerSphere in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geo

Currently, we are using $centerSphere to find nearby cities. One example is that for the locality Bee Cave in Texas, USA, $centerSphere correctly found the only city Austin in a radius of 30 kilometers (As per documentation, it was converted in **radians**). Now, for the city Lautoka in Fiji (Lat: -17.6169618, Long: 177.4504609) it is giving the error "Spherical distance would require (unimplemented) wrapping". This is question one: what does this error mean?

We tried implementing the same by using $center. I'm aware we need to give distance in miles rather than radians. After implementing, for Bee Cave, I got US cities that were thousands or hundreds of miles away. One example is Albuquerque. I'm unable to understand why these cities are coming even after following Mongo documentation properly.

I'm using the query (for Bee Cave, TX)

```
db.places.find{
   "geo": {
      $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ -97.9524, 30.3061 ] , 18.64 ] }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`$centerSphere` can't handle large distances, especially if it has to wrap around the poles, see this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2408).

Regarding `$geoWithin` it does not accept the distance in miles, but rather  the circle’s radius as measured in the units used by the coordinate system, so latitude and longitude as per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/center/#op._S_center). That results in a very large bounding box that does include Albuquerque

[image: bounding box]

You use `$near` instead that allows to specify a radius in meters. For example if you use this as your test data:

```
db.places.insert( {
   name: "Bee Cave, Texas",
   location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -97.9524, 30.3061 ]  }
} );
db.places.insert( {
   name: "Austin, Texas",
   location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -97.654724, 30.210768 ]  }
} );
db.places.insert( {
   name: "Albuquerque",
   location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -106.621216, 35.113281 ]  }
} );

db.places.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )
```

You can write the following query using the factor `1609.344` to convert miles to meter

```
db.places.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near:
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [-97.9524, 30.3061 ] },
            $maxDistance: 20*1609.344 
          }
       }
   }
)
```

This query returns both Bee Cave,TX and Austin, TX:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("5a7190124f0cd7075d349bbc"),
   "name":"Bee Cave, Texas",
   "location":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -97.9524,
         30.3061
      ]
   }
}{
   "_id":ObjectId("5a7190124f0cd7075d349bbd"),
   "name":"Austin, Texas",
   "location":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -97.654724,
         30.210768
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: So I have to give distance in radians when it always comes to geoWithin? They have not specified the same in the documentation of $center. At least for $centerSphere they have explicitly specified that we have to use radians. I'm still confused.

Comment: This is what is written for $center: "The following example query returns all documents that have coordinates that exist within the circle centered on [ -74, 40.74 ] and with a radius of 10". It just says radius of 10. Not one mention of any units.

Comment: "The circle’s radius, as measured in the units used by the coordinate system."

Comment: That is latitude and longitude in your case and matches your results (Albuquerque --> Bee Cave, Texas)

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you could use `$near` instead